# CMake can't find Qt4 but then finds Qt4

Tags: qt, ubuntu, cmake

I have the following in my CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(Qt4 4.8.6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)

target_link_libraries(debug Qt4::Core)
```

And I am getting the following error

```
Could NOT find Qt4 (missing: QT_CORE_INCLUDE_DIR QT_CORE_LIBRARY) (found
suitable version "4.8.6", minimum required is "4.8.6")
```

I ran `dpkg -l | grep qt` and I have libqt4-dev and `which qmake` returns `/usr/bin/qmake`.

Any ideas? I'm on Ubuntu if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper name for Qt4 "Core" component is `QtCore`. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505858/qt-libraries-in-cmake) as usage example.

---

The error message means that CMake has found QT4 **partially**: it has found basic libraries and include directories, but it has been unable to find things about "Core" component you ask. Note on `CORE` substring in missing variables' names.